# Show won't render correct json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am attempting to include some extra bits in my JSON using the below in my vehicles_controller:

```
  # GET /vehicles/1
  # GET /vehicles/1.json
  def show
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { @vehicle.to_json(:methods => [:product_applications_with_notes], :include => [:product_applications]) }
    end
  end
```

The vehicle model has both the method `:product_applications_with_notes` and the relationship `has_many: :product_applications`. However, when I run a request to `http://localhost:3000/vehicles/1` the JSON output is as below:

{
    "id": 1,
    "make": "Acura",
    "model": "ALL",
    "year": 2001,
    "body_style": "Car",
    "created_at": "2014-10-22T20:06:00.157Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-10-22T20:07:09.827Z"
}

It does not show the included extra bits. Why?

Comment: This might not be the issue, but try eagerly loading the `:product_applications` i.e `Vehicle.includes(:product_applications).find(params[:id])`

Comment: @Ali No dice. It didn't change the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to override the `as_json` method in Vehicle model.

something like:

```
  def as_json(options=nil)
    json_hash = super(options)
    json_hash[:product_applications] = product_applications

    json_hash
  end
```